# Remove a character from a string without knowing its position

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to remove a character ('.') from a string without knowing its position.
For example.

```
string test = "4.000";
```

But the '.' will always change.

Thanks!

Comment: surely you can just .replace() it?

Comment: Yes, I can, but for what?
If a use a replace, i need tu put something in its position, really?
I want just remove it.

Comment: You can replace with an empty string which will return the truncated result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to remove the first occurrence of that character:

```
string newString = test.Remove(test.IndexOf(".", 1));
```

If you want to remove **all** occurrences of that character:

```
string newString = test.Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: Yes, I used it. Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
string stringToReplace = ".";
string test = "4.000";
test = test.Replace(stringToReplace, "");
```